# What was the age of Sarah Connor when giving birth to John Connor?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles, the-terminator

We all know in the first two *Terminator* movies and in *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* seasons 1 & 2 John Connor's mother is **Sarah Connor.** I have two questions about her:

1. In the first two *Terminator* movies when Sarah Connor is giving birth to John Connor, what is her age?

[image]

2. In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, when giving birth to John Connor, what is her age?

[image]

Are there any differences between the movie and TV continuities in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the information on her [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Connor_(Terminator)) page:

> Very little is known about Sarah's life prior to May 12, 1984. The
>   Terminator does not specify her age or birth date, although according
>   to the original script (available on the Special Edition DVD), **she was
>   19 years old**. The film was primarily set on May 12–14, 1984; according
>   to the script, her birth date would be between May 15, 1964, and May
>   11, 1965.[citation needed]
>
> In Terminator 2: Judgment Day, Sarah's psychologist states she is 29.
>   The film takes place when John (born February 28, 1985) is 10, placing
>   Sarah's birth date between March 1, 1965, and February 25, 1967,
>   **making her either 17, 18, or 19 during The Terminator**. Many of the
>   franchise's hardcore fans and writers of "Terminator" novels have
>   speculated Sarah's exact date of birth is November 13, 1965, because
>   this date is compatible with her given age in The Terminator and her
>   stated age by the end of Terminator: **The Sarah Connor Chronicles** in
>   the final episode "Born to Run".[citation needed]
>
> The tombstone shown in Terminator 3 reads 1959–1997. This birth year
>   would make her 24 or 25 during The Terminator. She and John were
>   living "off the grid" in her adult years, routinely using false names,
>   birthdates, inter alia. Her tomb was really a weapons cache. She dies
>   of leukemia sometime after "Judgment Day" (August 29, 1997).
>   Terminator 3 changes John's age in the second film from 10 to 13,
>   introducing contradictions in the films' datings that cannot be
>   reconciled to one timeline.

Linda Hamilton was 27 when Terminator was made.

In terminator Genisys it also stated that Sarah is around 20 in 1984 (She mentions that she was 9 1973, when Pops saved here)